# UIView animation not working inside a KeyboardWillShowNotification event

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, notificationcenter

I am trying to animate a view during keyboard show/hide but it is not working, the animation is using the keyboard animation duration time instead of mine.

I found here that it is normal since the keyboard has an animation block provided by runtime. However it could be overriden by this as options: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/animationoptions/1622434-overrideinheritedduration

However, it is not working, it is ignoring my config and using the keyboard instead.. I tried to wrap the code with a Dispatch.main.async and sometimes it work and sometimes it doesn't.

Does anyone know how to fix it?

I thought it could be due to my constraing being update inside the keyboard block and since it has its own animation block it could be already updated when my custom animation runs, not sure if it makes sense.

```
    @objc func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {

         if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {


            constraint.constant = -300

            DispatchQueue.main.sync {
                 UIView.animate(withDuration: 15, delay: 0, options: [.overrideInheritedDuration], animations: {
                               self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
                           }, completion: nil)
            }


        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

UIView.animate is the Async task, so you don't need to use Dispatch Async :)
I don't know how you can detect the keyboard will appear or disappears and I think this's a problem
With my way, it works perfectly!
This is my code:

```
@objc func keyboardWillAppear() {
self.constraint.constant -= 100
UIView.animate(withDuration: 2, delay: 0, options: [.overrideInheritedDuration], animations: {
  self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
}) { _ in }
```

}

```
@objc func keyboardWillDisappear() {
self.constraint.constant += 100
UIView.animate(withDuration: 2, delay: 0, options: [.overrideInheritedDuration], animations: {
  self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
}) { _ in }
```

}

[image]